# a problem in serve in vue with Traversy Media vue course

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                3:14:42 PM
This relative module was not found:

* ./components/Tasks.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
```

im on archlinux(arco) and im using yarn  pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue tries to render Tasks.vue file, but that file could not be found, because it probably does not exist. So just create ./components/Tasks.vue! :)